# nginx: [warn] server name has suspicious symbols with long domain redirect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect, 301-redirect

What is the best way in Nginx to redirect two Long domains URLS, I would like to configure a redirect between two domains like this:

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works.

```
original link:

https://qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-science

New link

https://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science
```

I have tried this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-scienc;
    return 301 $scheme://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science$request_uri;
}
```

Still receive some errors

```
nginx: [warn] server name "education/7/abc-scienc
" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf:9

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

duplicate question as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74101316/long-url-diffrent-domain-redirect-nginx-issue

do these changes work for me :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.test.com;
    #old url
    location /education/7/abc-science {
        # Unique handler for the URL you want to redirect.
        # new url
        return 301 $scheme://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science;
    }
}
```

or do I need to add $request_uri; inside the location block

do I need to use this way to redirect from my old URL to the new one?

```
location = /content/unique-page-name {
  return 301 /new-name/unique-page-name;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? What is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Don't cross-post questions, if it belongs on SF ask it here, it it doesn't ask it on SO ; not both.

Answer (score 0):

[nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) states that `server_name` is the virtual server name (domain name) of the virtual host.

The documentation also explains what kind of input is allowed there.

You are trying to add a URL instead of domain, that is why the configuration is invalid.

You need to add a `location` block for the URI part of the URL.

Comment: ok, could you pl describe a bit with an example from my case?

Comment: @SantoshBaruah a search engine can return you millions of examples if the key words are "nginx" "config" "redirect" "example".

Comment: Thanks , do I need to add $request_uri; in the location, block to redirect to my old URL to the new Url ?